# Linq2DB can't translate a mapped column in Where clause

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c, linq2db

I'm working with a legacy Oracle database that has a column on a table which stores boolean values as 'Y' or 'N' characters.

I have mapped/converted this column out like so:

```
MappingSchema.Default.SetConverter<char, bool>(ConvertToBoolean);
MappingSchema.Default.SetConverter<bool, char>(ConvertToChar);
```

`ConvertToBoolean` & `ConvertToChar` are simply functions that map between the types.

Here's the field:

```
    private char hasDog;
        
    [Column("HAS_DOG")]
    public bool HasDog
    {
        get => ConvertToBoolean(hasDog);
        set => hasDog = ConvertToChar(value);
    }
```

This has worked well for simply retrieving data, however, it seems the translation of the following:

```
var humanQuery = (from human in database.Humans
                            join vetVisit in database.VetVisits on human.Identifier equals vetVisit.Identifier
                            select new HumanModel(
                               human.Identifier
                               human.Name,
                               human.HasDog,
                               vetVisit.Date,
                               vetVisit.Year,
                               vetVisit.PaymentDue
                                ));

// humanQuery is filtered by year here

            var query = from vetVisits in database.VetVisits
                        select new VetPaymentModel(
                            (humanQuery).First().Year,
                            (humanQuery).Where(q => q.HasDog).Sum(q => q.PaymentDue), -- These 2 lines aren't correctly translated to Y/N
                            (humanQuery).Where(q => !q.HasDog).Sum(q => q.PaymentDue)
                            );
```

As pointed out above, the `.Where` clause here doesn't translate the boolean comparison of `HasDog` being true/false to the relevant Y/N values, but instead a 0/1 and results in the error

`ORA-01722: invalid number`

Is there any way to handle this case? I'd like the generated SQL to check that `HAS_DOG = 'Y'` for instance with the specified Where clause :)

**Notes**

- I'm not using EntityFramework here, the application module that this query exists in doesn't use EF/EFCore

Answer (score 2):

You can define new mapping schema for your particular `DataConnection`:

```cs
var ms = new MappingSchema();
builder = ms.GetFluentMappingBuilder();

builder.Entity<Human>()
    .Property(e => e.HasDog)
    .HasConversion(v => v ? 'Y' : 'N', p => p == 'Y');
```

Create this schema **ONCE** and use when creating `DataConnection`

Comment: I re-read your answer, are you referring to EntityFramework mappings here?

Comment: Nope, this feature available in `linq2db`. I have personally developed that ;)

Comment: PogChamp - trying it out now.

Comment: Is there any of my code that I need to remove? I still seem to be running into the same issue

Comment: Probably remove `MappingSchema.Default.SetConverter<char, bool>(ConvertToBoolean); ...`. But ensure that mapping schema is passed to `DataConnection`. If you still have issue, try to prepare small sample and create issue in `linq2db`.

Comment: There is tests which uses this https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/c0cf9a59c5d55d0e7f150e91f325204c315436c0/Tests/Linq/Linq/ValueConversionTests.cs#L127-L157